# Array stored in array gets overwritten to the contents of the last one added

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Maybe it's something simple I'm missing, but I can't seem to figure out why my array of arrays is being overwritten with the last value in that is put into the array.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import class.ArgsProcessor;

public class Dice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArgsProcessor ap = new ArgsProcessor(args);
        int D = ap.nextInt("How many dice will be thrown each time?");
        int T = ap.nextInt("How many throws?");

        int[] dieThrown = new int[D];
        int [][] thrown = new int[T][D]; 
        double randomNum;

        for (int t = 0; t < T; t++){
            for (int d = 0; d < D; d++){
                randomNum = Math.random();
                if (randomNum < 1.0/6.0)
                    dieThrown[d] = 1;
                else if (randomNum < 2.0/6.0)
                    dieThrown[d] = 2;
                else if (randomNum < 3.0/6.0)
                    dieThrown[d] = 3;
                else if (randomNum < 4.0/6.0)
                    dieThrown[d] = 4;
                else if (randomNum < 5.0/6.0)
                    dieThrown[d] = 5;
                else
                    dieThrown[d] = 6;           
            }
            System.out.println("On throw " + (t+1) + " we rolled:");
            System.out.println("\t" + Arrays.toString(dieThrown));
            thrown[t] = dieThrown;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(thrown));
    }
}
```

Here's an example output for 3 dice thrown 3 times:

```
On throw 1 we rolled:
    [3, 4, 2]
On throw 2 we rolled:
    [1, 5, 4]
On throw 3 we rolled:
    [6, 5, 3]
[[6, 5, 3], [6, 5, 3], [6, 5, 3]]
```

However, I'm expecting something like this:

```
On throw 1 we rolled:
    [3, 4, 2]
On throw 2 we rolled:
    [1, 5, 4]
On throw 3 we rolled:
    [6, 5, 3]
[[3, 4, 2], [1, 5, 4], [6, 5, 3]]
```

How can I get it to add the right values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the same array object `dieThrown` to the array `thrown` multiple times.  Each iteration through the `d` for loop, you are overwriting the values in the same array, so the last iteration's values are the ones that remain.  The `thrown` array is full of references to the same array object referred to by `dieThrown`.

Create a new array in each iteration, separate from any previous iteration's array.  You can do this by moving the declaration of the `dieThrown` array:

```
int[] dieThrown = new int[D];
```

to the first line of the body of the `t` for loop, before the `d` for loop.

Comment: Could you explain why it overwrites those values? I guess when I read my code, I see:
   "for each throw, we write the die face in an array. We take that array and put it in slot 't'"
I guess I don't see the where the extra writing comes from.

Comment: Yes, you are taking that array and placing it in slot `t`, but `dieThrown` still refers to the same array in the next iteration.  That is why you must create  a new array each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

`dieThrown` is the same object throughout the program. You fill up your `thrown` array with references to the same object, and just replace its content in each iteration. So all your `thrown` entries basically point to the same place, and show the last content that has been assigned to `dieThrown`. To avoid that, use

```
dieThrown = new int[D]:
```

inside your outer loop, so that each element will be a separate array that will keep the content.

Answer (score 0):

You could also get rid of `dieThrown`. You can directly add it to `thrown`. Following is the code

public class dice {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int D = 3;
    int T = 3;

    int [][] thrown = new int[T][D];
    double randomNum;

    for (int t = 0; t < T; t++){
        for (int d = 0; d < D; d++){
            randomNum = Math.random();
            if (randomNum < 1.0/6.0)
                thrown[t][d] = 1;
            else if (randomNum < 2.0/6.0)
                thrown[t][d] = 2;
            else if (randomNum < 3.0/6.0)
                thrown[t][d] = 3;
            else if (randomNum < 4.0/6.0)
                thrown[t][d] = 4;
            else if (randomNum < 5.0/6.0)
                thrown[t][d] = 5;
            else
                thrown[t][d] = 6;
        }
        System.out.println("On throw " + (t+1) + " we rolled:");
        System.out.println("\t" + Arrays.toString(thrown[t]));
        //thrown[t] = dieThrown;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(thrown));
}
```

}

Notice I am adding to `thrown` directly

Output

```
On throw 1 we rolled:
    [5, 4, 4]
On throw 2 we rolled:
    [4, 4, 2]
On throw 3 we rolled:
    [6, 6, 6]
[[5, 4, 4], [4, 4, 2], [6, 6, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-using `dieThrown` each loop without creating a new array each iteration. You can solve this by moving the initialisation of `dieThrown` to the start of the outer loop (see it running here: [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/JxSohT)); or, a better solution, is to get rid of `dieThrown` and update the `thrown` array directly.

You can also simplify everything using [`java.util.Random#nextInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) instead of `Math.random`.

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/xx784F)

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    int D = 3;
    int T = 4;

    int [][] thrown = new int[T][D]; 
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int t = 0; t < T; t++){
        for (int d = 0; d < D; d++){
            thrown[t][d] = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        }
        System.out.println("On throw " + (t+1) + " we rolled:");
        System.out.println("\t" + Arrays.toString(thrown[t]));
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(thrown));
}
```